# Eclipse Neon installation on Windows 10 doesn't launch

Tags: java, eclipse

I recently downloaded the Eclipse Neon installer on Windows 10, but it doesn't launch. When I first downloaded it, it failed to find the Java VM. However, I installed Java SDK and now it doesn't show any error message, not even on command line, but still fails to launch.

I tried downloading the Eclipse IDE for Java Developers package from http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/eclipse-packages/, I just ended up with an incomplete 12MB zip file instead of the 161MB displayed on the website.

Please help, I wasn't able to find anybody else with my exact problem through my research.

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue, for some reason, Chrome stopped all my recent download at 12MB (both the installer and the package). I downloaded them under firefox and now everything is fine.

Answer (score 0):

You should [set up JAVA_HOME and update PATH](http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-set-java_home-on-windows-10/) variables to let JVM work properly